# HSQLDB: "invalid datetime format" for dd/mm/yyyy but not for yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, jdbc, hsqldb

My table creation is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
  id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 100, INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  department  VARCHAR(50),
  inventory_type VARCHAR(255),
  expiry_date date NOT NULL
);
```

Here are the insert statements into the table:

```
INSERT INTO inventory (name, department,inventory_type,expiry_date) VALUES ('om', 'Education','Raw', '01/01/2016');
INSERT INTO inventory (name, department,inventory_type,expiry_date) VALUES ('hari', 'HR','Solid' ,'02/02/2016');
INSERT INTO inventory (name, department,inventory_type,expiry_date) VALUES ('hariom', 'Finance','Other', '03/03/2016');
```

Unfortunately, I get

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid datetime
>   format    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
>   ~[hsqldb-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
>   ~[hsqldb-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
>   ~[hsqldb-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
>   ~[hsqldb-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:457)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]    ... 60 common frames
>   omitted

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

When I change statements like below, it's working fine:

```
INSERT INTO inventory (name, department, inventory_type, expiry_date) VALUES ('om', 'Education','Raw', '2016-01-01');
INSERT INTO inventory (name, department, inventory_type, expiry_date) VALUES ('hari', 'HR','Solid' ,'2016-02-02');
INSERT INTO inventory (name, department,inventory_type,expiry_date) VALUES ('hariom', 'Finance','Other', '2016-03-03');
```

Comment: What is your issue?  Use ISO 8601 standard date formats and everything works.

Comment: `'01/01/2016'` `'2016-01-01'` are Strings, not `date` values. `'2016-01-01'` just happens to be convertible to a date due to the evil implicit data type conversion.  See the manual on how to correctly specify  a data value: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_datetime_types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

The answer is simply that HSQLDB will only accept string literals for dates if they follow the `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format. It is willing to be helpful – to a point – in that it will allow us to omit the `DATE` keyword from a "proper" HSQLDB date literal value

```sql
DATE '2016-01-02'
```

and let us simply provide

```sql
'2016-01-02'
```

but it will not accept `'01/02/2016'` (which is ambiguous, anyway) or [any of the **many** other ways that we silly humans can represent dates](http://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: 01/01/2016 is not ambiguous, because by chance the day and month work out either way. 01/02/2016... not _that's_ ambiguous ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - "Silly" me. :) Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: If you want to convert, from the non-standard format, use  `TO_DATE( '01/01/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))`